# Sum up several files in emacs?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, summary

I have roughly a gazillion files of the same architecture. Is there a way to create a buffer which will present a summary of those files? possibly with org-mode?

Each file is formated as:

```
q   val    counts
1   0.05   2500
4   0.01   2500
10  0.002  2500
.
.
.
.
```

The files are each in their own folder:

```
prog
 |
 +fold1
 |  |
 |  ----file1
 +fold2
 |  |
 |  ----file1
 -fold3
    |
    ----file1
```

I'm not certain what should the summary conclude. I think that the first 3 lines + the averages of each file.

Comment: Please provide more context to your question. What should your summary contain? Are all these files in the same directory? Do they have special file names? You can probably solve it with org-mode source blocks calling a shell script.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding Juancho's comment, in `org-mode`, you can define a shell source block :

```
#+begin_src sh :results output raw replace
  for i in /path/to/files/; do
      head -n 3 $i
      # I let you compute the average you want using awk and whatnot
  done
#+end_src
```

and execute it with `C-c C-c` (cursor being in the block).

You may want to read the manual concerning [header arguments](http://orgmode.org/manual/results.html#results) if you want the results to be formatted in some particular fashion. (And you can do that in any language org-mode [supports](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages.html).)